# how to block all worker threads till the first worker thread not completed in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, webdriver-io, node-worker-threads

More than one workers thread are started when running test in parallel using WebDriverIO and node.js. There is a method which fetch and lock the data in database so next time different set of data to be fetched.

In current scenario when 2 workers are running and fetching data at same time, same set of data being fetched.

So I would like to block that fetchDbData method till first worker thread is not completed. Same kind of mechanism we can achieve using Synchronise keyword in Java.

Any suggesting how I can do that?
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

In order to synchronize access to the fetchDbData method in WebDriverIO and Node.js, you can use a combination of JavaScript's built-in Promise and async/await features.

like this you can restrict it and so one worker thread can access the fetchDbData method.

```
let isFetching = false;

async function fetchDbData() {
  if (isFetching) {
    // Wait for previous fetch to complete
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (!isFetching) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          resolve();
        }
      }, 100);
    });
  }

  isFetching = true;

  // Code to fetch data from database

  isFetching = false;
}
```

Hope it help you a bit!